# ORMLite for Android doesn't autorefresh foreign object using foreignAutoRefresh

Tags: java, android, foreign-keys, ormlite

Here's my problem: I have different entities linked to others up to a nesting depth of 3. All my foreign fields in every object are annotated with

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
```

But only up to a nesting depth of 2 I get actual autoRefreshed foreign objects.

For example, if I query for an A entity and then I do:

```
A.getB().getC().getD()
```

for entities B and C I already have all the fields, while for entity D I only have the ID fetched and I need to call the dao.refresh() method in order to fetch all of the D fields. Is it a limitation? I can't find anything about it on the documentation.

Comment: I've updated my answer @Andrea.  This was a bug in ORMLite unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the annotation attribute `maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 3` on the C entity, and D gets now refreshed.

The strange thing is that I didn't need to set maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel in neither A, B or D.

Another detail is that if I set to 2 the level for the C entity, D doesn't get refreshed anymore. Seems like the `maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 3` gets applied from the C entity to the "starting" entity, in my case A.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**

So after creating some better unit tests and looking into this more, this turned out to be a bug.  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) was handling the `maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel` setting in the `@DatabaseField` annotation incorrectly.  Right now (as you seem to have figured out looking at your answer) you need to add a `foreignAutoRefresh = true` and `maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 3` to the `C` field in your `B` object and the `D` field in the `C` object as well.  That should fix it.

I created the following bug report:

> https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3530801&group_id=297653&atid=1255989

I've fixed the problem in trunk and I've started the process of pushing out version 4.41.  It's been a while since the last release and this is as good a time as any.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Where am I supposed to use this annotation? I guess on the B field of the A entity. So now there's
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 4)
but still not working as expected (not refreshing).

Comment: Hrm.  That should work.  You do understand that it is only refreshed when you do a query, right?  Let me check the unit tests.

Comment: I am using a queryAll() method to retrieve all the A objects (A has maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 4 on the B foreign field). Then, A.getB().getC().getD() <-- it's not autorefreshed. Any clue?

Comment: All my objects have currently foreignAutoRefresh = true. What fixed my problem was adding maxForeignAutoRefreshLevel = 3 ONLY for the D field in my C object. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Oh I see.  Right that makes sense.  Although it counts the levels internally it uses the max on the local object and not the parent.  That has been fixed.